# ASP.NET MVC 5 HttpPostedFileBase always null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I checked everything and can't figure it out. The Form is multipart/form-data, the name of the input matches the name of the variable in the post method, and still the file is always null and Request.Files is always empty.

```
@model Gnosis.View.Areas.OpportunityAction.Models.Rfp.RfpModel
@using (Html.BeginForm(MVC.OpportunityAction.ChangeRfp.Edit(), FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id="submitForm" }))
{
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" style="width: 400px"/>
}
```

controller method

```
 [HttpPost]
    public virtual ActionResult Edit(HttpPostedFileBase file, RfpModel model)
    {
}
```

If I do an ajax post that works, but I should work with MVC mechanisms also and can't figure it out why it doesn't...

Update. This is the code in the view:

```
@model Gnosis.View.Areas.OpportunityAction.Models.Rfp.RfpModel
@using (Html.BeginForm(MVC.OpportunityAction.ChangeRfp.Edit(), FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id="submitForm" }))
{

@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SystemEditDate)
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Attachment)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Description)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.FileSize)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.FileDate)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.FileTime)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.FileExtension)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.OpportunityRfpId)

<table class="keyvalue withrowpadding">
    <tr>
        <td class="key">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Rfp)</td>
        <td class="value">@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Rfp)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="key">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.RfpDate)</td>
        <td class="value">@Html.EditorFor(m => m.RfpDate)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="key">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.FileName)</td>
        <td class="value">@Html.TextBox("NameForDisplay", Model.FileName, new {disabled = "disabled", style = "width:300px"})</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="key">RFP File Name:</td>
        <td class="value"><input type="file" name="file" id="file" style="width: 400px"/> @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Attachment)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <input type="submit"  name="submit" value="Save" id="Save"/>
            <input type="button" value="Cancel"/>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
@Html.ValidationSummary()
}
<script>
    $(document).on('click', '#Save', function () {
        var vcfData = new FormData($('#submitForm')[0]);
        var rfp = $("#Rfp").val();
        var rfpDate = $("#RfpDate").val();
        var id = $("#Id").val();
        var opportunityRfpId = $("#OpportunityRfpId").val();
        console.log(id);
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action(MVC.OpportunityAction.ChangeRfp.SubmitFile())' + "?file=" + vcfData + '&id=' + id + '&Rfp=' + rfp + '&RfpDate=' + rfpDate + '&OpportunityRfpId='+ opportunityRfpId,
            type: "post",
            data:  vcfData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The code is inherited, and probably the original developer couldn't figure out this puzzle either so he did the ajax post. But I need to expand this functionality, and it needs to be done in the Edit method and dependent on processing of this file...

Comment: the overload you use seems to be incorrect! Are you sure this code is rendering the desired HTML markup ?

Comment: What do you mean incorrect?

Comment: Should it be like `@using(Html.BeginForm("Edit","Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "submitForm" }))
{` ( missing the controller name ?

Comment: I am using T4MVC and MVC.OpportunityAction.ChangeRfp.Edit() will be translated at runtime to the right controller/action . The data gets posted, the model is populated, just the file it's null.

Comment: Does your code generate the correct markup ? Does the form has the `enctype` attribute ?

Comment: yes, the form looks like this:<form action="/OpportunityAction/ChangeRfp/Edit" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="submitForm" method="post"><input type="file" name="file" id="file" style="width: 400px"/></form>

Comment: What you have show should work fine and its something you have not shown us causing the issue. Do you have another input in the view with `name="File"`? Is here any javascript in the view?

Comment: No other input named file, and I have some javascript that posts the file through ajax, but I commented that out and still nothing. I'll post an update with the view.

Comment: @OanaMarina, I know you said you comment out the script - but much of the code in that script is pointless - its just `url: '@Url.Action(MVC.OpportunityAction.ChangeRfp.SubmitFile())',` (you `var vcfData = new FormData($('#submitForm')[0]);` correctly serializes all the form controls and its all sent using `data:  vcfData,` - adding them again to the url as query string parameters is just pointless